# Mass Updating Entities from DTO

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, automapper, ef-core-2.0

Are there any ways to mass update an Entity from a DTO using Automapper in EF Core?

I keep getting an entity already tracked error.

I've tried looping through the change tracker and setting all of the entries to detached and nothing seems to work.

Mostly what I wanted to do was this:

```
var entityAs = Mapper.Map<List<EntityA>>(DtoAs);
MyContext.UpdateRange(entityAs);
MyContext.SaveChanges();
```

I also tried this:

```
var entityAs = Mapper.Map<List<EntityA>>(DtoAs);
MyContext.AttachRange(entityAs);
MyContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: "entity already tracked error" usually means you're reusing DbContext instances in ways you shouldn't.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Could you give me an example by chance? We use dependency injection and inject our context into the accessor class I'm using

Comment: With Dependency Injection, you would typically inject the DataContext into the HTTP Request.  So each new request starts with an empty change tracker.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft
Sorry if my terminology is off... I believe that's what we do. 

In the startup.cs file we have a line services.AddDbContext<Context>(....) that should set this with every request, right?

I believe that should add it correctly to be used for each connection.

Comment: Are there perhaps duplicates in your list of entities?

Comment: There aren't but I may have queried the parent entity before this in another accessor. 

After querying for that entity I use the data that was returned to filter it down and then I wanted to do an update on a small subset of the original items, which is when I ran into my problem

Comment: If you are going to use DTOs you typically _also_ disable change tracking on your queries.

Comment: Oh really? I had no idea. I guess I was afraid that it would not save correctly. Disabling change tracking does work so I guess that is the solution.

Comment: Are you sure that your mapped entities do not have duplicates (2 or more items with the same Id as configured in your Context). Tried to reproduce your code and exception was only thrown when I duplicated items, otherwise i could save items just fine with a simple `context.UpdateRange(...)`. Can u inspect your `entityAs` to see if it doesnt contain duplicate keys?

Comment: So I believe the issue was caused by me querying a parent entity and then doing the updaterange with the child entities.

Potentially the issue was caused by whoever set up DI using scoped for all of our accessor classes....